# Several rows highlighted when using AllLinesData.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have interesting issue about
`DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)AllLinesData.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(AllLinesData.SelectedItem)` (C#, WPF)

I'm using this code to highlight one row from DataGrid. However, it highlights selected row and some random rows:

```
private void cellTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (AllLinesData.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)AllLinesData.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(AllLinesData.SelectedItem);
        if (row != null)
        {
            rowNotes[row] = cellTextBox.Text; // Сохраняем текст для соответствующей строки
            SolidColorBrush BrushColor = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#3393378B"));

            row.Background = BrushColor;
        }
    } 
}

private async void AllLinesData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (AllLinesData.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        // Получаем выбранную строку
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)AllLinesData.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(AllLinesData.SelectedItem);


        // Убеждаемся, что строка не находится в режиме редактирования и что это именно ваш объект данных
        if (row != null && !row.IsEditing && row.DataContext is TextData)
        {
            cellTextBox.Text = rowNotes.ContainsKey(row) ? rowNotes[row] : "";

            // Получаем позицию курсора
            Point cursorPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
            cellTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            cellTextBox.Opacity = 0;

            // Устанавливаем начальное положение TextBox
            Canvas.SetLeft(cellTextBox, cursorPosition.X - 100);
            Canvas.SetTop(cellTextBox, cursorPosition.Y);
            // Запускаем анимацию появления
            DoubleAnimation opacityAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = 0,
                To = 1,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3) // Время анимации
            };
            cellTextBox.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, opacityAnimation);

            // Ожидаем завершения анимации (если нужно)
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3));
        }
    } 
}
```

Like this:

- **(not selected)** Item1 - Good Square **(Color white)**
- **(Selected)** Item2 - Square **(Color red)**
- **(not selected)** Item3 - System **(Color red too, but I was not selected)**

How to deal with this problem?

I tried to change this method, but it is the best for my work.

Screenshoot of my program:

[image: issue]

Comment: what does the whole method look like?  Also, if you put a breakpoint in that if statement, is that breakpoint being triggered multiple times?  Definitely going to need more debugging details to help you out.

Comment: I am using it in here private async void AllLinesData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

 DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)AllLinesData.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(AllLinesData.SelectedItem);

AllLinesData is DataGrid

Comment: And no, breakpoint being triggered only once. I can add screenshot

Comment: @sous2817, I've added screenshots in post